# Why is animation not working (CSS/JS/jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am creating a slide-in menu, and what i want to do is when the user clicks on an image, the menu slides in. I have used everything, CSS animations, jQuery animation, and still not working.
`

```
            <div id="nav-slide-unvisible">
                <!-- Image that toggles animation -->
                <img id="image" src="arrow.png">

                <ul>

                    <li>Bla bla</li>
                    <li>Bla bla</li>
                    <li>Bla bla</li>
                    <li>Bla bla</li>
                    <li>Bla bla</li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>`
```

I used `transform: translateX(-240px)` in CSS, applying it to`<nav id="slide-nav">` 
This is the jQuery code:

```
$("image").click(function() {
            $("slide-nav").animate({
            '-webkit-transform':'translateX(242px)'
            ,'-moz-transform':'translateX(242px)',1000);
                               });
```

But debugger generates an error "SyntaxError: missing : after property id"
Thanks.

Comment: try `$("#image").click(function() {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is a result of the missing curly brace in the object passed to the `animate` method:

```
$("#image").click(function() {
     $("#slide-nav").animate({'-webkit-transform':'translateX(242px)',
                             '-moz-transform':'translateX(242px)'},1000);
 });                                   // The one that goes here ^
```

Comment: Not quite, it goes before the ,1000 as it's supposed to close the object. Also, image and slide-nav's aren't id's, so he's missing some #'s as well

Comment: @DrunkWolf Good callouts. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("image").click(function() {
            $("slide-nav").animate({
            '-webkit-transform':'translateX(242px)'
            ,'-moz-transform':'translateX(242px)',1000);
                               });
```

change it to

```
$("#slide-nav").animate({
```